# ExtJS: Getting a Model field out of a TreeStore that does not use an explicit Model

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I'm trying to get a model field that is stored in my database from a TreeStore that is using NodeInterface.
I have the current node but, I don't know how to traverse the node to get to the underlying model and that particular field for the current node.

This is all being displayed in a TreePanel.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set any model then the default fields are added from NodeInterface. If you look in the source code you see the list of default fields:

```
    this.applyFields(modelClass, [
        { name : 'parentId',   type : idType,    defaultValue : null,  useNull : idField.useNull                },
        { name : 'index',      type : 'int',     defaultValue : -1,    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'depth',      type : 'int',     defaultValue : 0,     persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'expanded',   type : 'bool',    defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'expandable', type : 'bool',    defaultValue : true,  persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'checked',    type : 'auto',    defaultValue : null,  persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'leaf',       type : 'bool',    defaultValue : false                            },
        { name : 'cls',        type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'iconCls',    type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'icon',       type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'root',       type : 'boolean', defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'isLast',     type : 'boolean', defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'isFirst',    type : 'boolean', defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'allowDrop',  type : 'boolean', defaultValue : true,  persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'allowDrag',  type : 'boolean', defaultValue : true,  persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'loaded',     type : 'boolean', defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'loading',    type : 'boolean', defaultValue : false, persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'href',       type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'hrefTarget', type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'qtip',       type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'qtitle',     type : 'string',  defaultValue : '',    persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'qshowDelay', type : 'int',     defaultValue : 0,     persist : false          , convert: null },
        { name : 'children',   type : 'auto',    defaultValue : null,  persist : false          , convert: null }
    ]);
```

Once you have the node (that inherits from Model), you just call:

```
node.get('expandable'); // or other field you need
```